# Exclude Test folder and Resources from Gradle Jar build

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, repository

I am trying to create a Jar to be used as a Maven Repository

I have everything built out and all the classes are ready to go. Only problem is that the gradlew ./build is including the classes and resources from the test folder. I don't want these as part of the jar, especially the resource files under test.

So my question is, How do I exclude these files from my jar build task. I tried

```
tasks.named('jar'){
    exclude('PATH/src/test/')
```

in my build.gradle but that didn't work

I am a newbiew at gradle and maven so any insight would help. Thanks!

Reference Material

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.project.tools'
version = '1.0.0'


repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'

    implementation platform('io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.1.0')
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

}

tasks.named('jar'){
    manifest {
        attributes('Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': project.version)
    }
}
```

**File Structure**

```
project/
├─ tools/
│  ├─ build/
│  │  ├─ classes/
│  │  │  ├─ new_folder/
│  │  │  │  ├─ main/
│  │  │  │  ├─ test/  #I Don't Want This Here, This Classes Do Not Need To Be Accessible
│  │  ├─ generated/
│  │  ├─ libs/
│  │  ├─ reports/
│  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  │  ├─ test/  #Would rather not have this entire folder
│  │  │  │  ├─ com.project.tools/
│  │  │  │  ├─ test.properties  # Definitely Do Not Want This Included
│  │  ├─ test-results/
│  │  ├─ tmp/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ main/
│  │  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  │  ├─ com.project.tools/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ MyClasses.java
│  │  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  ├─ test/
│  │  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  │  ├─ com.project.tools/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ MyTestClasses.java
│  │  │  ├─ resources/
│  ├─ build.gradle
```

Comment: Have you actually looked into the generated jar? `test` classes and resources are not included by default, so unless you changed something it should already be correct.

Comment: Damn you right, they were not included. Like I said I am new to java. Figured what ever was listed in the classes folder was included on the JAR. Thanks, could you submit your comment as an Answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle does the right thing by default, there is no need to manually exclude `test` classes/resources from the `jar`.